# Save and load cell border information from strings

Tags: c#, border, cell, spreadsheetgear

I´m trying to save the border information of a cell to a string variable and use the string to create borders for another cell, but I simply can't figure out how to do that.
I have seen that you can get some border information using

```
.Cells[2, 0].Borders[SpreadsheetGear.BordersIndex.EdgeTop].ToString();
```

But I can´t figure out how to use the string to give border information to another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders for a cell would need to be specified using the IRange.[Borders](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Borders.html) property.  Note this property can also be indexed into so that you can apply a specific border style/color/weight/etc. on a specific "edge".  Example:

```
// Set border options for all "edges" of B2.
worksheet.Cells["B2"].Borders.Weight = BorderWeight.Thick;

// Set border option for the "right edge" only.
worksheet.Cells["B2"].Borders[BordersIndex.EdgeRight].Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Red;
```

You can find a sample in the SpreadsheetGear Explorer Solutions for C#/VB (found in the "SpreadsheetGear" folder under the Start Menu, if you have SpreadsheetGear installed on your machine) under *Range > Border* which demonstrates this API further.  There's also an online version of this sample that utilizes the SpreadsheetGear for Silverlight product [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/silverlight.aspx?InitSample=SilverlightSamples.Range.BorderSample).